# React redux saga - getting some odd behaviour

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I am in process of learning how to use reactjs, redux, react-redux and redux-saga. My attempt at this in my public github repo, found here:

> https://github.com/latheesan-k/react-redux-saga/tree/5cede54a4154740406c132c94684aae1d07538b0

My **store.js**:

```
import { compose, createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";

import reducer from "./reducers";
import mySaga from "./sagas";

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const composeEnhancers =
  typeof window === "object" && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        // TODO: Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
      })
    : compose;

const storeEnhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware));

export default createStore(reducer, storeEnhancer);

sagaMiddleware.run(mySaga);
```

my **actions.js**

```
export const HELLO_WORLD_REQUEST = "HELLO_WORLD_REQUEST";
export const HELLO_WORLD_RESPONSE = "HELLO_WORLD_RESPONSE";
export const HELLO_WORLD_ERROR = "HELLO_WORLD_ERROR";

export const helloWorldRequest = () => ({ type: HELLO_WORLD_REQUEST });
export const helloWorldResponse = text => ({ type: HELLO_WORLD_RESPONSE, text });
export const helloWorldError = error => ({ type: HELLO_WORLD_ERROR, error });
```

and my **sagas.js**

```
import { put, takeLatest } from "redux-saga/effects";

import { HELLO_WORLD_REQUEST, helloWorldResponse, helloWorldError } from "./actions";

function* runHelloWorldRequest(action) {
  try {
    // TODO: real api call here
    yield put(helloWorldResponse("Hello from react-redux-saga :)"));
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(helloWorldError(e));
  }
}

export default function* mySaga() {
  yield takeLatest(HELLO_WORLD_REQUEST, runHelloWorldRequest);
}
```

and my **helloWorldReducer.js**

```
import { HELLO_WORLD_RESPONSE } from "../actions";

export default (state = "", { type, text }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case HELLO_WORLD_RESPONSE:
      return text;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and this is how put it all together on my `App` component:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.helloWorldRequest();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>{this.props.responseText}</p>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ responseText: state.helloWorldReducer });
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => bindActionCreators({ helloWorldRequest }, dispatch);

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

This works fine, but here's the odd behaviour I am trying to understand. In order to get the response value out of the state and map it into props, I had to do this:

> const mapStateToProps = state => ({ responseText:
>   state.helloWorldReducer });

Based on what I saw in the react devtools:

[image]

Notice after the request is processed and a response is generated; the resulting state object contains a field called **`helloWorldReducer`**.

Where did this come from?

I assumed this field name should have been called **`text`**.

P.S. Sorry about the long post; still learning react-redux-saga, so I didn't know which part of my code was relevant to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the resulting state object contains a field called helloWorldReducer.
>
> Where did this come from?

It comes from your root reducer which is actually the reducer created by using the `combineReducers()` method.

This is your `reducers/index.js` file which export the root reducer for creating redux store:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import helloWorldReducer from "./helloWorldReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  helloWorldReducer   // here
});
```

Comment: I see. If I wanted to return a more complex object, rather than just `text` (string value), how would I go about doing that? also, how will I get to that object on my component?

Comment: well then, instead of the string value, your state will be replaced by an object. And you can get to that object just the way you used to get to the string value.

Comment: Just try to replace the state with an object, if anything go wrong, I'll always be here to support ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am understanding this a little bit more now. Got this working the way I need it now: https://i.imgur.com/RIYRDfj.png / my reducer now looks like this: https://pastebin.com/KcX6xciM / and I can access complex object field's value like this in my component: `state.helloWorldReducer.responseText`